# What type of file has a number as the file extension?

Tags: file-format

https://github.com/anatol/tup/blob/master/tup.1

It seems barely readable, what editor do I need for this?

Comment: It's a man page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a manual page. You can view it by downloading the file and doing this command in a terminal window (assuming you're on a UNIXy system like Linux or Mac OS X):

```
man path/to/tup.1
```

You can edit it with any text editor.

A little bit of extra info:

Man pages all end in the extensions `.1` through `.8` to refer to what section of the manual they belong to. Here is a list of the sections and their numbers*:

1. General commands
2. System calls
3. C library functions
4. Special files (usually devices, those found in /dev) and drivers
5. File formats and conventions
6. Games and screensavers
7. Miscellanea
8. System administration commands and daemons

*: List of sections from the [Wikipedia page on man pages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page#Manual_sections).

Answer (score -1):

Technically, it's plain text, i.e. any text editor can edit it.  As for what it's saying... It looks like some sort of scripting language, but not one I recognize.  From line 365, `Tup begins parsing this Tupfile`, I'm assuming the file is using the syntax and language for Tup, but I'm not entirely sure what Tup is since I haven't looked at it yet.

As an aside, file extensions don't really mean anything.  They're just a "rule of thumb" for determining file types.  A lot of plain text files either have no extensions or "unconventional" extensions, like .old or .bak for backup copies of files, or .1 for file one.

Comment: No, it isn't. This is a man page.

Comment: It IS plain text, technically, but I admit that I haven't seen a raw manpage before.

Comment: Right, it is. But it isn't any sort of "scripting syntax" file.